# How to zip all folders and subfolders in a directory (individually)?

Tags: python

I would like to zip **each** folder and subfolder found in a directory. What is the best way to go on about this? Should this be done in bash or python? Suggestions and tips are welcomed.

UPDATE:

I have been able to develop a python script that extracts files from sharepoint and batches them into different subject folders. Every 300 files are numbered and batched - eg. Cars have 15,000 files, folders are subsequently called Cars1 (0-299 files), Cars2 (300-599) etc...

This question has now been resolived:
https://gist.github.com/msunardi/6527ac4c3b08975d30f83cd8aa80e147

Answer (score 1):

Revised:

Consider using 'find' and 'zip' to perform individual zip for each folder.

```
for d in $(find /path/to/folder -type d) ; do
    zip $d.zip $d/*
done
```

Comment: Could you elaborate further? Lets say my directory was C:\Users\nmouk\Documents   and I wanted to zip all 10 folders individually..do I have to name each file I would like to zip?

Comment: I might have misunderstood original question. See script to perform zip on individual folders.

Answer (score 1):

With apologies for the similarity to @dash-o's solution, I wanted to elaborate on the redundancy this will cause as described if the target glob isn't specific.

I created a sample folder structure:

```
$: find a
a
a/b
a/b/d
a/b/d/foo
a/b/e
a/b/e/foo
a/b/f
a/b/f/foo
```

all single-letter elements are directories, `foo` is files.

```
$: while read d; do echo zip ${d//\//_}.zip "$d"; done < <( find a -type d )
zip a.zip a
zip a_b.zip a/b
zip a_b_d.zip a/b/d
zip a_b_e.zip a/b/e
zip a_b_f.zip a/b/f
```

`a.zip` will hold the whole structure. `a_b.zip` will contain everything but the `a` directory. If you ONLY want the bottom levels, you'll need a glob that defines them all as a clear set -

```
$: while read d; do echo zip ${d//\//_}.zip "$d"; done < <( find a/b/? -type d )
zip a_b_d.zip a/b/d
zip a_b_e.zip a/b/e
zip a_b_f.zip a/b/f
```

`find a/b/? -type d` is pretty simple for my example. Can you make one that does that?